# docker-compose add another service url to environment variable

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

Working on dotnet microservices project but having issue to bind environment variable to another services exposed url on docker.

Let me explain:

Here is my docker-compose.override.yaml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
    
  frontend:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:80
      - ProxyUrl=http://appprx
    ports:
      - "5100:80"

  appprx:
    volumes:
      - ./Envoy:/etc/envoy
    ports:
    - "5202:80"
    - "15202:8001"
```

What I get from frontend services application is: `http://appprx`

Bu it should be `http://localhost:5202/`

Comment: Where are you seeing the incorrect URL; what produces it?  What in your application code or configuration (not just the Docker setup) knows about the 5202 port?

Comment: @DavidMaze actually I've seen this approach in eShopOnContainers sample application on microsoft's dotnet architecture guide. But then I figured out it's not working on there as well. But they did it. I'm seeing the environment variables via `docker exec frontend env` and the value of ProxyUrl is: http://appprx